# Adobe Premiere - How To Copy Animation to Another Projects?

Tags: premiere, adobe

Hello I've made text animation with some background and it's slowly fading into video, now I want to recopy this same animation style to another Premiere video projects.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can create the text animation as a sequence in your original project.  Then you can import the sequence in a new project. https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/importing-sequences-clip-lists-libraries.html